# Google data studio connector - getFields() get config data

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm trying to build connector to pull data from REST API. In config section you have to add token in order to get proper data for selected user.

```
function getConfig(request) {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var config = cc.getConfig();

 config
  .newTextInput()
  .setId('token')
  .setName('Enter token');

  return config.build();
}
```

In getData() I call this token

```
var url = API_URL + '/user_data.php?token=' + request.configParams.token;
```

and that work ok. But since the fields in getFields() are different depend of user I will need to use the same token to identify the correct list of fields. I have tried something like this but this dont work.

```
function getFields(request) {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var fields = cc.getFields();
  var types = cc.FieldType;
  var field_list = [];
  var options = {
    'fields_token' : request.configParams.token
  };

  var fields_url = API_URL + '/get_user_fields.php';

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fields_url, options).getContentText();
  var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
  var parsedFields = parsedResponse['fields'];

  for(var i = 0; i < parsedFields.length; i++) {
    field_list = parsedFields[i];

    fields.newDimension()
     .setId(field_list)
     .setType(types.TEXT);
  }

  return fields;
}
```

When I run it I get error message

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'configParams' of undefined

Can someone please help me where Im wrong?

Comment: on the line above `var cc=....` put `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(request));` and look at executions and let us know what is in the request  object.  My guess is that it's undefined

Comment: What is `fields_token` supposed to be? Part of the payload of the request? Also, how are you executing this function?

Comment: When I add Logger.log I get null in return. The fields_token should grab the value that user enter in token from config section. Same token work ok in getData() function but for some reason its not working in getFields().

Comment: The [Data Studio connector reference](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference) doesn't show `getFields` as one of the functions. How is it called?

Comment: The connector is based on this example https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors#7

Comment: @Martí is correct. `getFields` is just a helper function. It is not really needed. In the example, it is used by `getSchema` and `getData` but it does not has any parameters. To access configParams from it, you should add this parameter and assure it is passed to the function when invoked.

Comment: If would be helpful if you can also share your `getSchema` code.

Comment: Thank you all, I have move everything to getSchema and its work now.

Answer (score 1):

The error (`Cannot read property 'configParams' of undefined`) is explaining that you are using `somthing.configParams` where `something` is `undefined`. In the code, the variable that you are doing this is `request`, so basically it's `undefined`.

`request` is a parameter of `getFields(request)`, which is a function that you invoke manually. Thus, you are invoking `getFields` with `undefined` as a parameter. The most likely scenario is that you are calling `getFields()` (notice the missing parameter).